# Dynamic Sprite Image Generate In memeory

Tags: html, css, performance, sprite, css-sprites

I am having a webApplication which showe user records in tabular formate (200 row at a time). Problem is these rows contains multiple images and they are served based on the request URL.this results in a request being generated per image, which leads to performance decay.

Question:

> Is it possible to create spriteImage for dynamic images? I'm looking for  something that I can use in order to aggregate these images into a single sprite at runtime without storing it into disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to generate the images as [Data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). This would include all the image data in the response, ready to be displayed by the browser without making additional requests.

I.e. instead of a normal HTML page where you'd have

`<img src="http://myserver.com/img/123.png"/>` which would create a request to the server, you would include the data directly in the page as
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />`

If you're not satisfied even with that, the last option would be to bunch up all the images to a single huge image, load that offscreen and use CSS trickery to grab parts of the big image to be displayed.

If all else fails, get a beefier server, they're not *that* expensive.

Comment: This will increase the response size (by huge margin) which will slowdown all record rendering process.